# "Like" system php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, performance

Im trying to make a php/mysql version of a like or upvote system. I know basically how to do this and have seen other threads on how to do this. The only issue is I do not want to allow users to like the status more than once. I was wondering what would be the most efficient way to do this?

I have a few choices so you know Ive thought about it but perhaps you can tell me whats best/reccomend a better way:

1) In the database I could store a column that just stores a string representation of all the users that like this status. That way when I query that status/number of likes I can also get that string, tokenize it and check if the user is in there. If not, add a like and concatenate them to the string.

2) Create a new table where it stores key value pairs. So if user1 likes user2 status then it adds a row [user1, user2] to the table, then if they try to like it again it checks if that row exists and doesnt allow it. This however could be problematic I think because if there are a 1000 statuses at a given time and every person "liked" all 999 other statuses then my table now has nearly a million rows that need to be stored and queried when checking if theyve liked it.

Comment: Your option (1) is how I've done it in the past and it's fine, but it requires that users are logged in. For anonymous 'liking' you'd do the same thing but with IP addresses instead of user IDs.

Comment: Go with number 2. Searching a billion rows, each with two int columns, is far quicker than concatting strings, and searching concatted strings.

Comment: Approach 2 is what relational databases are made for. The amount of data is not significantly higher than approach 1 with the csv list (see `FIND_IN_SET` btw). The coding effort and maintenance probably the same.

Comment: What about unliking? If they are concatted you would have to update the row, with approach 2 you add, delete and select without concerns about what else is there.

Answer (score 0):

I made a *like* system for my own company. This is what I did:

I had a table of **likes** which had the following information: id, user, number_likes

The id for counting rows, user for tracking the user id and number_likes for tracking what the user is liking. For example, if you are liking articles.

You could have a table of **articles**: id, article_id, ...

Now, just have a like button that inserts information to **likes** and where *number_likes* matches *article_id*.